# How to show and hide in angular in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show/hide some elements when user clicks certain buttons

I have 3 buttons.

```
<a href='#' ng-click = 'show()'>button 1</a>
<a href='#' ng-click = 'show()>button 2</a>
<a href='#' ng-click = 'show()>button 3</a>
```

coordinate with 3 elements

```
<img src='img1' ng-show='img1Show'/>
<img src='img1' ng-show='img2Show'/>
<img src='img1' ng-show='img3Show'/>
```

under my controller

I have

```
    $scope.img1Show = true;
    $scope.img2Show = true;
    $scope.img3Show = true;

$scope.show = function(){
      //I want to control show and hide status 
}
```

Click once on button 1 will show the image1 and click again will hide the image1.

I want to know the most effective way of doing this. Do I really need `img1Show` to `img3Show`? Thanks.

Comment: what is more effective than having a simple variable in scope like you do? perhaps I do not understand the question.

Comment: I am just wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a live demo for you.
check it out at
http://plnkr.co/edit/jAWkDU

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="show1 = true">show 1</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="show2 = true">show 2</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="show2 != show2">toggle 2</a>


    <h1 ng-show="show1">11111</h1>
    <h1 ng-show="show2">22222</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a data binding framework. You need three variable to mark status for each img indeed.

But `show()` is not required.

You can directly toggle them by `ng-click`:

```
<a href='#' ng-click="img1Show = !img1Show">button 1</a>
<a href='#' ng-click="img2Show = !img2Show">button 2</a>
<a href='#' ng-click="img3Show = !img3Show">button 3</a>
```